# Is there a difference in speed between the spider and cavespider?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I have been exploring an abandoned mineshaft lately in minecraft and I saw regular spiders and a cave spider spawner. The cave spiders seemed to be a lot quicker than the regular spiders. Is this true, or are they the same speed or are the regular spiders quicker. If I am wrong about the cave spiders being faster, do they appear to be faster because they are only one block wide?

Answer (score 2):

Regular spiders and cave spiders move the same speed and in the same manner.  The only difference between the two is their size, their colour and the poison that the cave spider has.

Comment: So the cave spiders only seem to go faster because they are tiny?

Comment: I would assume so.  Your eyes can deceive you.

Comment: Regular spiders get stuck on walls more often since they're so wide, so cave spiders are faster in practice.